# how can i fix failing to load resource status 404 github pages

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I have deployed my project on Github and it gives this

[image: img_error]

errors on the console and how may i fix it?

and link to the git is: https://blessja.github.io/Bottelary/

github repo: https://github.com/blessja/Bottelary

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Just so you know, best practice is to include the text of your code and error messages in the body of your question, rather than as an image. You can update your post using the 'Edit' button. (Check out the discussion behind this advice in this post on meta: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the incorrect file URLs in the `index.html`.
**For example**, you have written **`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">`** which targets to **[`https://blessja.github.io/css/main.css`](https://blessja.github.io/css/main.css)**, which gives a error 404.
Instead type **`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">`** or **`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">`** which will get you to the right file, i.e. **[`https://blessja.github.io/Bottelary/css/main.css`](https://blessja.github.io/Bottelary/css/main.css)**

**And try changing all the incorrect file paths mentioned in the `index.html` file.**